# How to correctly extend typescript class?

Tags: typescript

I get puzzled in the following problem. The last line `m.removeChild(m.childNodes[0])` is complained by ts compiler.
I have no idea whether `childNodes: BaseNode[];` is correct in this case.

```
class BaseNode {
  childNodes: BaseNode[];
  constructor() {
    this.childNodes = [];
  }
  appendChild(node: BaseNode) {
    this.childNodes.push(node);
  }
}

class MyNode extends BaseNode {
  removeChild(node: MyNode): void {
    const index = this.childNodes.indexOf(node);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.childNodes.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}

const m = new MyNode();
m.appendChild(new MyNode());

// Argument of type 'BaseNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyNode'.
// Property 'removeChild' is missing in type 'BaseNode' but required in type 'MyNode'.(2345)
m.removeChild(m.childNodes[0]);
```

Comment: `removeChild(node: MyNode)` - `removeChild` only accepts `MyNode`s, but `m.childNodes[0]` is only guaranteed to be a `BaseNode` (which **might not** be a `MyNode`). It's not clear what you're hoping to achieve with inheritance here, you could just have one class.

Comment: You probably want `removeChild(node: MyNode): void` to take a `BaseNode` instead. That will make your example compile successfully. I guess it can be confusing because `appendChild` works because `MyNode` is assignable to `BaseNode`, while `removeChild` doesn't work because `BaseNode` isn't assignable to `MyNode`

Comment: If you're doing subclassing this way you might look into using [polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAyg4m).  Does that approach work for you? If so I could maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Cool, this works for me! But I got another problem when using `this` in the constructor.  [See my code here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMByB7AJg6BvAUNawAFgJYhqoYQBc0ALiRANoC6A3HgSgHYS0BOAV2C0UfABQAHMHwRdaFBAH4a9YhACU2DvmIAzaJOmz56BJtz5L0KTLkKAdGAkTZaAMIkyY1RvZWAvtp0DPZEpOSmMAC80Cx+0IH4Ti5c7p5oYlymKgzmQT6h6QoQ9hICEISZpurxgYE4oJAwALIAngrQCAAetK4w8BDIplr4MgC2KABuCB7hVRg5auo0kyjEaCOWwNy80MSp3dAxBWFkxfb7GF0A8rrzZvE6+mKXhwB8MQAMeVb4J0WRewQCQgYjABAvA5dAA00AAjDUgokEjh6tseLRoGMjtAuAgAO7QNoKMSIsaOZyuWZePGE4mmUmIgD0TOg1wA0gBCHDk8ZTGbpMTk04RSiMT7MRFAA)

Comment: Yes, that's a known limitation/missing feature, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38038.  If that's important to you, could you [edit] your example code to show this use case?  Right now there's no great way to deal with that using `this`, and so if it matters, you might need a different approach.

Comment: For example, you could make `BaseNode` explicitly generic instead of using `this` (a sort of "implicit" generic), like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WKqKKN).

Comment: If you've answered your own question, it should be posted as an actual answer and as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jcalz 's answer, I change all `BaseNode` type in class `BaseNode` to `this`, and it works in most cases, but using type `this` in the constructor is still unsupported by TS compiler.

```
class BaseNode {
  childNodes: this[];
  // Error in constructor
  // A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface.
  constructor(parentNode?: this) {
    if (parentNode) {
      parentNode.appendChild(this);
    }
    this.childNodes = [];
  }
  appendChild(node: this) {
    this.childNodes.push(node);
  }
}

class MyNode extends BaseNode {
  removeChild(node: this): void {
    const index = this.childNodes.indexOf(node);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.childNodes.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}

const m = new MyNode();
m.appendChild(new MyNode());
// OK!
m.removeChild(m.childNodes[0]);
```

---

Finally, I changed the type of `parentNode` in constructor parameters to `unknown`, then check its type in constructor body. Maybe this is not the best method, but now I can only do something like that.

```
constructor(parentNode?: unknown) {
  if (parentNode instanceof BaseNode) {
    parentNode.appendChild(this);
  }
  this.childNodes = [];
}
```